# Cursor navigation between dual monitors is backwards

Tags: monitor

Okay, so i have a new dual-monitor set-up, but you know how when you move the mouse to the left, it goes to the screen on the left, and visa versa? Well, for me, i have to move my mouse to the RIGHT to get it to go to the screen on the LEFT, and visa versa. can anyone help me fix this without moving my monitors? Please, its getting all my nerves...

Comment: We need more information about your setup, specifically what kind of video card you have, how is it connected to the monitors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the free program *arandr* to arrange your displays how you like them.

From a terminal, Install arandr:

```
$ sudo apt-get install arandr
```

run arandr

```
$ arandr
```